# How do you deal with an outgoing commit to a closed branch in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I made a commit to a branch but did not push it. In the meantime, that branch was closed, and I made more commits to other branches. I am now getting an error when trying to push unless I push one branch at a time. The error makes sense, since that's the whole point of closing branches, but how can I "throw away" my commit? I don't want it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove that commit from your local repository as well. Mercurial has for this task the `strip` command ([which is its own extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension), but it is shipped by default and only needs activation). Thus in your .hgrc, your mercurial config file you need

```
[extensions]
strip =
```

The mq extension provides the same facility. Once enabled you can remove your unwanted commit **along with all of its descendants**:

```
hg strip -rXXX
```

where XXX is the changeset you want to remove. The grain of salt: be careful with it, maybe make a local clone of your repository *before* you use strip, as stripping is a history-editing action which is not easily undone.

Answer (score 1):

Closing branches should not by themselves prevent you from pushing. A closed branch is simply a branch that ends in a commit that carries the "closed branch" meta information. You can reopen a branch by simply committing to it again (at which point, the most recent commit doesn't have the "closed branch" meta information and so the branch is considered open again). The only purpose of closing a branch is so that it doesn't show up in "hg branches".

You didn't mention the error you are getting, but I would assume that it comes from somebody else doing a close branch commit and you committing elsewhere, so now the branch has two heads, and you can't push a new head without `-f`. As always in such a case, the answer would be to merge both heads (your commit and the closed-branch head [1]) and then push.

[1] Or alternatively, rebase your commits on top of the closed branch head.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, my question was poorly phrased and the error was caused by multiple heads. I didn't want to merge, however, because the branch was closed.